# How to revert to classic authentication for Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-authentication

I've been following various tutorials on Azure B2C authentication and none of them are updated to use the new "authentication experience" within the function app settings. As someone just trying to set up a basic test, this has proven very frustrating as it's not clear what to fill in since some of the terminology and settings the tutorials say to use don't exist (or possibly have a different name) in the new authentication experience. Anyway, just for the sake of diagnosing some authentication issues I'm having, I wanted to try using the classic auth experience. However I don't seem to be able to do that. I tried deleting my identity provider in the new auth experience as well as setting allow unauthenticated access for auth settings, but I still don't seem to be able to revert back to the classic setttings.

Is there a way to delete my new auth experience and revert back to classic? I just want to diagnose where I'm going wrong with my test and this is the only area where I wasn't able to follow the tutorial 1 to 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:-

Connect-AzAccount
$tenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id

Password based authentication

$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName ServicePrincipalName

$sp.secret | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText

$pscredential = Get-Credential -UserName $sp.ApplicationId
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId

For automation scenarios, you need to create credentials from a service principal's applicationId and secret:

$pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($sp.ApplicationId, $sp.Secret)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId